# How to increase an width:auto DIV's width by X pixels using pure CSS

Tags: css, html, width, transition

I have a **DIV** (that is set to *float:left*) that has its *width* set to *auto* because i want it to be just as wide as its contents.

On *hover*, i would like to increase *width* of the **DIV** by say, 20 pixels.

When setting a fixed *width* in the *:hover* CSS class, the container will get that *width* on hover, but

1. CSS3-Transitions won't apply/work (tested in Firefox 15.0.1)
2. If my **DIV**'s contents are larger than that fixed *width*, the final *width* will not be correct.

How - without the usage of javascript - can i keep the content of the **DIV** adjusted to its content, and have it increase that width by a certain amount of pixels on hover?

[See my JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jKU9F/)

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst - the question says "without the usage of javascript" and the title is "using pure CSS".

Comment: Can you post some code in jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the link. Done now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your fiddle, though I'm not sure this is the exact effect you need, try this:

```
.myDiv:hover {
    padding-right: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me the easiest way to do this was to increase the content by a percentage higher than 100%. E.g.:

```css
width: 110%;
```

But if you want to increase the size in `n` pixels as asked, you can use

```css
width: calc(100% + 50px);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the default padding to 0 and the hover padding to 10px on each side like shown here.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YWvTu/

```
.myDiv {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -i-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.myDiv.alternative {
    width: 100px;
}
.myDiv:hover {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Perfectly correct! alcidesqueiroz was a few seconds faster, but please leave your answer in for other users to get more input on the matter.