# How to set width of a <hr/> in CSS to X number of pixels less than the width:auto?

Tags: html, css

I have a nav with some `<hr/>` elements. Preferably in pure CSS (3?), how would set the width of the horizontal rules to auto minus X number of pixels?

<sub>This does not duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878354/how-to-increase-an-widthauto-divs-width-by-x-pixels-using-pure-css), because it is for what would equate to negative padding, which is impossible.</sub>

Comment: Have you thought about using the CSS3 calc function? Docs at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc. Browser support: http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the below.

```
hr {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 10px; /* This leaves 10px margin on left and right. If only right margin is needed try margin-right: 10px; */
}
```

Comment: The sentence “If only right is needed try margin-right: 0px;” sounds odd. Presumably one occurrence of “right” should be “left”.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin-right`

Or you could use Javascript for something more specific. For eg:

**CSS:**

```
hr {
   margin-right:20px;
   width:auto;    
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9EfPM/)**