# Make inner element wider than parent element by a set amount

Tags: html, css

I have an element inside another element, and I would like that inner element to be wider than the parent by a set amount - lets say 40px.  So it would look like this if the parent was 500px wide:

[image: Example of the effect I'm after]

But if the parent is 600px wide, for example, I'd like the child to be 640px wide.

**Without tying the outer element to any particular width, I'd like the inner element to always be 40px wider than the outer element. Is there a CSS only way to achieve this?**

Comment: I suggest you go with @vikas answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the width increase, but you can give padding of inner div via css which may work for you.

You can give your inner div css like

```
.innerDiv {
    /*padding-right: 20px; */
     padding:20px;  /*this will give to left and right side 20px padding*/
}
```

[How to increase an width:auto DIV's width by X pixels using pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878354/how-to-increase-an-widthauto-divs-width-by-x-pixels-using-pure-css)

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer because it benefits from wider browser support.  (You might also include a mention that for this to work, `box-sizing` must be set to `content-box`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `calc` for this.

For inner div, just provide following details

```
.inner {
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

Comment: darn, beat me to it! +1 to useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">Parent Content
    <div id="child">Child content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    width:500px;
    min-height:200px;
    border:2px solid green;
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#child {
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    padding:0 20px;
    border:2px solid red;
    color:red;
}
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ycc26mw5/)

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycc26mw5/1/)

Comment: The problem with padding is that available area inside `div` will still be 100% of parent

Answer (score 1):

you can use calc functionality in CSS.

```css
div.parent {
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    background:#f00;
}
div.child {
    height:100px;
    width:calc(100% + 40px);
    z-index:1;
    background:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps